# Does $G=\langle A,g^{-1}Ag\rangle$ imply that $ G=Ag^{-1}Ag$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian subgroup of a finite group $G$. We can assume that $G$ is generated by sets $A$ and $g^{-1}Ag$ for some element $g$ contained in $G$. Does it follow from this assumption that  $G=Ag^{-1}Ag$?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please format your math with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

First of all $Ag^{-1}Ag = A(g^{-1}Ag)$ isn't a subgroup if $A$ isn't a normal subgroup of $A$. Being abelian doesn't imply normality in general.

For a counter example take $S_4$ and let $A=\langle (12),(34) \rangle$, which is abelian (and not normal in $S_4$), as it's isomorphic to the Klein 4-group. Take $g=(132)$, then $g^{-1}Ag = \langle (23),(14) \rangle$. Now $S_4 = \langle A, g^{-1}Ag \rangle$. But the set $A(g^{-1}Ag)$ has $16$ elements, which can't be a subgroup of $S_4$.

Comment: A smaller example is $A = \langle (1,2) \rangle < S_3$ with $g = (2,3)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yeah you're right! I knew that $S_4$ has abelian non-normal subgroup and I tried to make use of it, without thinking much about any other example